# UPDATE a json list type column in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sql-update

I got a json type column named 'attr' which was used to store a list include some dict like `[{"foo":1}, {"foo":2}, {"foo":3}]`.

Now I want to extend the list to `[{"foo":1}, {"foo":2}, {"foo":3}, {"foo":4}]`. Of course I can use a sql query like:

```
update tbl
set attr='[{"foo":1}, {"foo":2}, {"foo":3}, {"foo":4}]'::json;
```

However, I need execute it in my webserver. So I must select the former value, extend the list and then update into table.

I'm thinking if there is a way to use some postgresql function to do this like `array_to_json` or `json_array_elements`

I wrote this query:

```
update tbl
set attr = json_build_array(json_array_elements(attr), '{"foo":4}'::json);
```

But it got wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the data type `json`:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    attr = (
   SELECT json_agg(elem)
   FROM  (
      SELECT elem
      FROM   json_array_elements(attr) elem
      UNION  ALL
      SELECT '{"foo":4}'::json
      ) sub
   )
WHERE  tbl_id = 123;  -- determine row to update
```

For the data type `jsonb`:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    attr = (
   SELECT json_agg(elem)::jsonb
   FROM  (
      SELECT elem
      FROM   jsonb_array_elements(attr) elem
      UNION  ALL
      SELECT '{"foo":4}'::jsonb
      ) sub
   )
WHERE  tbl_id = 123;
```

The aggregate function `json_agg()` always returns `json`, even when called with `jsonb` input. So we need another cast to `jsonb`.

Obviously you want to limit your `UPDATE` to a specific row, so add a `WHERE` clause.

Don't go to the underlying table a second time in the subselect, just work with the value from the target row.